# Call a function later

Tags: c++

I'm parsing user input and doing, as an example, the following in response:

**User Input 1:**

```
Array<int> a;
Populate()(a);
int v = 10;
a.append(v);
```

**User Input 2:**

```
Array<bool> a;
Populate()(a);
int v = true;
a.remove(v);
```

**User Input 3:**

```
Array<bool> a;
Populate()(a);
a.removeAll();
```

Now lets say I wish to execute the functions at a later stage, such that the parse creates the Array object, establishes the command to execute for this Array(removeAll etc.) as well as the arguments, but doesn't actually call the command - this calling occurs at a later stage.

Is there a std or boost library which might help me to do achieve such a behaviour?

Comment: I don't see "The Array object". I see three distinct objects of different types.

Comment: The technique you refer to is called "expression template", I think: A lazy evaluation class that encapsulates your intention, but doesn't execute it until needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C++11 you can remember the action in `std::function`:

```
std::function<void()> action;
Array<int> a;

Populate()(a);
int v = 10;
action = [&a,v] () { a.append(v); };
```

Note, that when you call the action, it will work on the exact Array you gave it (it is captured by reference), so make sure the object still exists!

Answer (score 3):

In C++11 you can use [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [std::bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) to store function objects that you can call later. In C++03 you can use [boost::function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/function.html) and [boost::bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/bind/bind.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just program your 3 functions and assign one of them depending on the user input to a function pointer. Later you just call the function pointer.