# How to store a functor for later invocation in C++

Tags: c++, lambda, callback, invoke, functor

This question might be naïve, if so please forgive me as I am learning.

Please consider the following C++-like **pseudo code**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>


struct A{
    bool doSomething(int in){
        std::cout<<"SOMETHING WAS DONE THAT DAY: "<<in<<std::endl;
        return true;
    }
};

struct B{
    std::function executor;

    void setExecutor(std::function f){
        executor=f;
    }

    bool doSomethingLater(int in){
        return executor(in);
    }
};

static bool yoloFunction(int in){
    std::cout<<"LIVING LA VIDA LOCA: "<<in<<std::endl;
    return false;
}


int main()
{
  A myExecutor;
  B lazyAss;

  // Storing member function for later invocation
  lazyAss.setExecutor(&myExecutor::doSomething);
  bool result_1 = lazyAss.doSomethingLater(1337);
  std::cout<<"The first result is "<<result_1<<std::endl;

  // Storing regular function for later invocation
  lazyAss.setExecutor(&yoloFunction);
  bool result_3 = lazyAss.doSomethingLater(42);
  std::cout<<"The second result is "<<result_2<<std::endl;

  // Storing lambda function for later invocation
  lazyAss.setExecutor([=](int in){
    std::cout<<"P- P- P- POKERFACE!: "<<in<<std::endl;
    return true;
  });
  bool result_3 = lazyAss.doSomethingLater(666);
  std::cout<<"The third result is "<<result_3<<std::endl;

}
```

It should illustrate what I am trying to accomplish, namely to **store a callback of some kind for later invocation**.

So how would I go about doing this in modern C++ in the simplest way possible, without using boost or other non-standard dependencies?

What options and caveats are there?

Things to note are that the signature of the callback is known in advance and will not change.

Also the callback I want to store may be of different forms like  stand alone function, member function or lambda.

Comment: You might want to check out Stephan T Lavavej's Youtube talk on functional https://youtu.be/zt7ThwVfap0

Comment: Does not compile?  error: invalid use of template-name ‘std::function’ without an argument list

Comment: _"Please consider the following C++-like pseudo code:"_ That's not helpful. Provide a [mcve] reproducing your problem, and elaborate about your doubts regarding the error messages you see (cite these as verbatim text please).

Comment: You really should boil it down to the actual problem. Is your question about how to correctly set the template arguments for `std::function`, is it about how to save a member function bound to an object into `std::function`, or another question? [How to store arbitrary method pointers in c++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30448056), [Call a function later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050684), [How to bind, store and execute a std::function object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532512), ...

Comment: My problem is I don't know how to do it. If I knew the correct code I would write it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify struct B like this:

```
struct B {
    std::function<bool(int)> executor;

    void setExecutor(std::function<bool(int)> f) {
        executor = f;
    }

    bool doSomethingLater(int in) {
        return executor(in);
    }
};
```

In main(), use a lambda to pass the member function as parameter like this:

```
lazyAss.setExecutor([&](int i)->bool { return myExecutor.doSomething(i); });
```

Comment: Thanks that was useful!